# Submit ExtJS form to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, extjs4

I´m in troubles when I need to submit the form data back to rails.

When using default html rails update page, I get a params variable like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"V", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"+70K0Mrgy7LhwtW46Em7LgQnz10vqxOjfbldHAiB2MA=",
"pessoa"=>{"nome"=>"paulo2", "cpf"=>"1234", "data_nascimento(1i)"=>"2012", "data_nascimento(2i)"=>"6", "data_nascimento(3i)"=>"29"}, 
"commit"=>"Update Pessoa", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"pessoas", "id"=>"1"}
```

But when submit from ExtJs, I get only this:

```
{"nome"=>"paulo2", "cpf"=>"1234", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"pessoas", "id"=>"1", "format"=>"json"}
```

By now, this is the code to load the record:

```
form.getForm().load({
    url: '/pessoas/1.json',
    method: 'get',
            ...
```

and this is my code to submit form:

```
var submitForm = function(){
    form.getForm().submit({
        url: '/pessoas/1.json',
        method: 'PUT'
    });
};
```

There is a special way to send data to rails or I need to work with this data in rails ?

Comment: method put is reserved for REST interface. Are you trying to use REST?

Comment: no at all. None configuration about this.